Gradient estimate for second-order uniformly elliptic equation in divergence form
Motivation for the following question: I am currently reading this paper by Bernard and Rivière. In Lemma VI.1 in equation (VI.10), they seem to apply a certain estimate for the gradient of an equation of the type
$$\Delta f = \text{div}(g)\quad  \text{ on some domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$}.\tag{1}$$
(For additional information about the problem: In the paper, at least restricting to dimension 3, $f = \vec H$ is the total mean curvature of a (conformal) immersion and $g = 3\nabla (\vec n \otimes \vec n)(\vec H) + \nabla^\perp \vec n \times \vec H$, where $\vec n$ is the normal vector field so that $|\vec n|=1$. We have good bounds for $\nabla \vec n$ and $\vec H$, however not for $\nabla \vec H$. Also $\nabla^\perp = (-\partial_{x_2}, \partial_{x_1})$).
The paper states a pointwise estimate for $\nabla f(x)$, depending on $\|g\|_{L^\infty}$ and $\text{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$. I strongly suspect (also due to the fact that this paper argues similarly in equation (3.84)) that they apply Theorem 3.9 from Gilbarg and Trudinger. For completeness, this theorem states that for a $C^2$-solution $u$ of $\Delta u = h$ in $\Omega$, it holds
$$\sup_{x\in \Omega} \text{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)|Du(x)| \leq C(\|u\|_{L^\infty} + \sup_{x\in \Omega} \text{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)^2 |h(x)|). \tag{2} $$
Now my question is basically how to obtain estimates for (1), either using this theorem (2) or by some other method. Notice that I cannot apply (2) directly to (1) as I don't have good estimates for $\text{div}(g)$, just for $g$ itself.
If needed, I gladly give more context to the situation.
